# save a label's property to a file for reading and writing in visual studio 2010

Tags: vb6, vb.net-2010

I was recently making a project in Visual Studio 2010. I was creating a Windows Application in which I wanted to save a label's property to a file and by clicking a button on the form, it would read the file and restore the label's property. I was able to do it in vb6 but I cannot do it in Visual Studio 2010 as their languages are a little different. This is what I wrote in VB6:

This was the code for saving the label

```
    Open "Time Table" For Output As #1
    Write #1, Label4
    Close 1
```

Code for loading the label

```
    Open "Time Table" For Input As #1
    Input #1, Label4
    Close 1
```

So my question is that what should I do in Visual Studio 2010 to make this code work.

Any help appreciated
Regards,
SMKH

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm misreading your question you simply want to read and write to a file in VB.NET.

If so there are plenty of examples on the web, try [this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315828) for a start, also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/db5x7c0d.aspx). Stripped down to a minimum your code should be something like this:

```
'Write
Using outfile As New StreamWriter("Time Table")
    outfile.Write(Label4.Text)
End Using

'Read
Using sr As New StreamReader("Time Table")
    Label4.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

Addendum: [There's an excellent example of serialization here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316730).

Comment: It seems that you know what I want. If I have to write multiple label's to the file, should I write outfile.write() in the next line for a few times or should I do something else. Also, please clear this problem for reading too. Your code seems to be working just perfect but along with the label's text, I want to save it's backcolor, width and height too.

Comment: @SMKH It's time you started to do some research for yourself rather than relying on others. However, in short, if you want to write store multiple values in a file then you'd be better off creating an object and serializing it. Read up on serialization and deserialization, it's both cool and invaluable.

Comment: I would never have posted the question here if i could find my answer on the web. However I am new to VB.NET and am the age of 13 so I thought this site could increase my knowledge. Anyway, I have found out how to write it for more than 1 label but am still confused for reading the size and backcolor of the label(I was successful in writing it).